# How to reuse Azure startup tasks?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have an app which needs to be installed for all the services I have. Unfortunately, installation requires many files and task related input parameters (e.g. RoleInstanceValue xpath=...).

The way I came up with to share this task among cloud service projects is through Azure Plugins (here is a link to a library of them http://richorama.github.io/AzurePluginLibrary/).

The problems I see with this approach are:

- It is not recommended/supported by Microsoft, which means they can
  change support for that any time.
- It requires copying files to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft
  SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.6\bin\plugins\NxlogAzureForwarder`, adding an
  extra step to build setup.

Microsoft recommends startup tasks. But I could not figure out a way to share them among cloud services.

So, my question is: how to **easily** reuse startup tasks?

Answer (score 0):

As recommended your best chance would be a startup task that starts your app, which would be encapsulated into a Windows service. That service is going to be your reusable task/app/service (whatever you call it).

What you need extra is the following:

- Project reference to your Windows service
- An install script for the service
- Installer tool
- (Optional) app config for your service

To start your app/service you need to update cloud service definition by adding start up task and making runtime context elevated, and start your service in `OnStart` entry point.

That being said, you can place parameters of your app in the cloud config and read them in your `WebRole` and pass them to your service.

For more detail check out [this post](http://mertemin.github.io/thoughts/2015/07/15/best-practices-of-deploying-windows-services-to-azure/).